# In a quantum state, Maximum how many protons & neutrons can exist?

Tags: quantum-spin, neutrons, protons, pauli-exclusion-principle, quantum-states

This is in reference to the statement I have read in a book i.e., " each quantum state can contain at the most two protons (with opposite spin) & two neutrons (again with opposite spin)".
So what I actually want to know is that, is this statement true in every condition or some certain condition?
Also this confusion arises because, we have heard that one Quantum state only contain one electron.
That's why, I want to make it confirm.

Comment: The book is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Pauli exclusion principle applies only for fermions i.e particles that obey Fermi-Dirac statistics and have half integral spin like electrons, protons, neutrons etc. It states that no two fermions can occupy the same quantum state within a quantum system. So only a single fermion can occupy a specific quantum state in a quantum system.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84831/discussion-on-answer-by-mechanic7-in-a-quantum-state-maximum-how-many-protons).